# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose with connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

These are the errors I received:

```
(node:11692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-01-wwvto.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket. (C:\Node Example\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at _handle.close (net.js:606:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7)
```

```
(node:11692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by
rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

```
(node:11692) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: DId you register your local Ip to mongodb Atlas?

Comment: Not registered. Could you please guide me to do that bec i am beginner to this.

Comment: White list all IPs,
IPs life matter :p

Answer (score 18):

Yes you can always add your local IP Address by going to:

Security - > IP Whitelist and then add a new IP.  There you can click "ADD CURRENT IP ADDRESS" along with any comment:

[image: Atlas Whitelist]

Comment: Make sure that when your IP gets changes you'll need to add over there but if you allow for anywhere then that problem will be solved